# Error when launching dataflow pipeline from cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a pipeline from a google cloud function.
Unfortunately, I cannot get passed the first lines of all the examples I found.

I installed the google apis :

```
npm install googleapis --save
```

This is the code I'm trying to run for now:

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const dataflow = google.dataflow('v1b3');
```

However I get the following error:

```
const dataflow = google.dataflow('v1b3');
                        ^

TypeError: google.dataflow is not a function
```

From all the examples I've seen, this should be enough to give a dataflow client.

Comment: Just curious, why do you have the necessity to launch a pipeline from a Cloud function? Is it possible to instead write a single continuously running streaming pipeline?

Comment: I need to run my pipeline every 6 hours. that's why I'm looking into a solution like: GAE Cron -> pubsub -> Cloud function -> Dataflow

Comment: I'm working with python sdk, I want to launch a pipeline through a cloud function. Ps : hi have different files , each file has a different pipeline. 
I tried to do subprocessing within the cloud function, it did not work. 
I didn't understand the use of google APIs in your question. what was the idea and the procedure behind that? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made this work by changing the code to:

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');
```